# Export extension list for Visual Studio Code on WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am on Windows 10 with WSL2 (Windows Subsystem für Linux) activated (Alpine and Ubuntu as distro), I use Remote-WSL inside VScode. On my "normal" VScode I can do `code --list-extensions` to get all my extensions.

How can I do it on a WSL-Remote Terminal (zsh, bash)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code communicates to WSL2 via a server component installed on the Linux machine, which apparently as of now doesn't support the `--list-extensions` flag.

The following output difference between the same command, `code --list-extensions` typed in Windows and WSL shows it

On WSL

```
code 1.49.0

Usage: code [options][paths...]

To read from stdin, append '-' (e.g. 'ps aux | grep code | code -')

Options
  -d --diff <file> <file>           Compare two files with each other.
  -a --add <folder>                 Add folder(s) to the last active window.
  -g --goto <file:line[:character]> Open a file at the path on the specified line and 
character position.
  -n --new-window                   Force to open a new window.
  -r --reuse-window                 Force to open a file or folder in an already 
opened window.
  --folder-uri <uri>                Opens a window with given folder uri(s)
  --file-uri <uri>                  Opens a window with given file uri(s)
  -w --wait                         Wait for the files to be closed before returning.
  --locale <locale>                 The locale to use (e.g. en-US or zh-TW).
  -h --help                         Print usage.

Extensions Management
  --enable-proposed-api <extension-id> Enables proposed API features for extensions. 
Can receive one or more extension
                                       IDs to enable individually.

Troubleshooting
  -v --version                       Print version.
  --verbose                          Print verbose output (implies --wait).
  --log <level>                      Log level to use. Default is 'info'. Allowed 
values are 'critical', 'error',
                                     'warn', 'info', 'debug', 'trace', 'off'.
  -s --status                        Print process usage and diagnostics information.
  --prof-startup                     Run CPU profiler during startup
  --disable-extensions               Disable all installed extensions.
  --disable-extension <extension-id> Disable an extension.
  --sync <on> <off>                  Turn sync on or off
  --inspect-extensions <port>        Allow debugging and profiling of extensions. 
Check the developer tools for the
                                     connection URI.
  --inspect-brk-extensions <port>    Allow debugging and profiling of extensions with 
the extension host being paused
                                     after start. Check the developer tools for the 
connection URI.
  --disable-gpu                      Disable GPU hardware acceleration.
  --max-memory                       Max memory size for a window (in Mbytes).
```

On Windows

```
Visual Studio Code 1.49.0

Usage: code.exe [options][paths...]

To read output from another program, append '-' (e.g. 'echo Hello World | code.exe -')

Options
  -d --diff <file> <file>           Compare two files with each other.
  -a --add <folder>                 Add folder(s) to the last active window.
  -g --goto <file:line[:character]> Open a file at the path on the specified
                                    line and character position.
  -n --new-window                   Force to open a new window.
  -r --reuse-window                 Force to open a file or folder in an
                                    already opened window.
  --folder-uri <uri>                Opens a window with given folder uri(s)
  --file-uri <uri>                  Opens a window with given file uri(s)
  -w --wait                         Wait for the files to be closed before
                                    returning.
  --locale <locale>                 The locale to use (e.g. en-US or zh-TW).
  --user-data-dir <dir>             Specifies the directory that user data is
                                    kept in. Can be used to open multiple
                                    distinct instances of Code.
  -h --help                         Print usage.

Extensions Management
  --extensions-dir <dir>
      Set the root path for extensions.
  --list-extensions
      List the installed extensions.
  --show-versions
      Show versions of installed extensions, when using --list-extension.
  --category
      Filters installed extensions by provided category, when using --list-extension.
  --install-extension <extension-id[@version] | path-to-vsix>
      Installs or updates the extension. Use `--force` argument to avoid prompts. The identifier of an extension is always `${publisher}.${name}`. To install a specific version provide `@${version}`. For example: 'vscode.csharp@1.2.3'.
  --uninstall-extension <extension-id>
      Uninstalls an extension.
  --enable-proposed-api <extension-id>
      Enables proposed API features for extensions. Can receive one or more extension IDs to enable individually.

Troubleshooting
  -v --version                       Print version.
  --verbose                          Print verbose output (implies --wait).
  --log <level>                      Log level to use. Default is 'info'.
                                     Allowed values are 'critical', 'error',
                                     'warn', 'info', 'debug', 'trace', 'off'.
  -s --status                        Print process usage and diagnostics
                                     information.
  --prof-startup                     Run CPU profiler during startup
  --disable-extensions               Disable all installed extensions.
  --disable-extension <extension-id> Disable an extension.
  --sync <on> <off>                  Turn sync on or off
  --inspect-extensions <port>        Allow debugging and profiling of
                                     extensions. Check the developer tools for
                                     the connection URI.
  --inspect-brk-extensions <port>    Allow debugging and profiling of
                                     extensions with the extension host being
                                     paused after start. Check the developer
                                     tools for the connection URI.
  --disable-gpu                      Disable GPU hardware acceleration.
  --max-memory                       Max memory size for a window (in Mbytes).
  --telemetry                        Shows all telemetry events which VS code
                                     collects.
```

Note the `Extension Management` section of the output

Comment: Thanks. I did the same observation :-) Do you have any idea, how to solve my issue? In the extension menu, I see the hint "installed" or "installed to WSL xyz" but I cannot get this on command line.

Comment: I don't think it's possible until Microsoft adds it. If you want you can ask on their gitter or open an issue of the vscoce github page and hopefully someone verified will respond

https://gitter.im/Microsoft/vscode
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @dopewind, vscode in WSL doesn't support --list-extensions flag.
You can get the list by inspecting the vscode UI html:
Open vscode in WSL, go to Help>Toggle Developer Tools.
Select Extensions, and filter them by Installed.
Select the Extensions div in Developer Tools, then go to Console to print the list with:
`$0.innerText`

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever tried extensions.json?

When I switch between WSL and Windows to manage extension between platform, I use extensions.json approach.
More details, [Click Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery)

You should be creating extensions.json within the .vscode folder.

I am not sure if my solution helped the question, but it provides different perspective of managing extensions easily across the team.

Answer (score 0):

`code --list-extensions` will only show extensions installed on the WSL VSCode Server. To get a list of extensions installed on the Windows client from WSL, you'll need to manually launch the `code` CLI. This is because the `code` executable does some logic to determine if you're running on WSL and launch the code-server cli instead of the code cli.

Unfortunately, to launch the client's cli manually, you need to jump through a few hoops.

---

Firstly, WSL doesn't allow arbitrary environment variables to be passed to Windows paths, which is required to run scripts with Electron. You'll need to modify the `WSLENV` env var explicitly.

```bash
export WSLENV="ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE/w:$WSLENV"
```

Second, you need the full path to the Electron executable (`Code.exe`) and the cli script. These are typically located in Windows at `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js`. For reference, the code executable is at `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code`

Now you can actually run the program.

```bash
ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" --list-extensions | dos2unix
```

Note the call to `dos2unix`. Since node/electron is running under Windows, it will output Windows line endings (CRLF).

---

If you want to run this in a bash script, here's a snippet to add to the top of your file.

This is adapted from the code executable. The main difference is `code` makes a few more checks for outdated WSL versions.

```bash
if [ -z "$(type -p dos2unix)" ]; then
    dos2unix() {
        sed -e 's/\r//gm'
    }
fi

if [ -n "$WSL_DISTRO_NAME" ]; then
    # default code cli in WSL won't show client side extensions

    export WSLENV="ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE/w:$WSLENV"
    VSCODE_PATH="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(realpath "$(which code)")")")"
    ELECTRON="$VSCODE_PATH/Code.exe"
    CLI=$(wslpath -m "$VSCODE_PATH/resources/app/out/cli.js")
    
    code() {
        local -a args
        for arg in "$@"; do
            # translate WSL paths to Windows
            args+=( "$(wslpath -m -- "$arg")" )
        done
        ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" "${args[@]}" | dos2unix
    }
fi

code --list-extensions --show-versions
```